# Threads stopped print characters and all of them are waiting for lock

Tags: java, java-threads

I want to use 3 threads to print `A`、`B`、`C` randomly,so I wrote code as below:

```
public class ThreadPrint4Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ThreadPrint4Test().testPrint();
    }

    public void testPrint() {
        Object lock = new Object();
        new Thread(new PrintThread("A",lock),"thread-A").start();
        new Thread(new PrintThread("B",lock),"thread-B").start();
        new Thread(new PrintThread("C",lock),"thread-C").start();
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        new Thread(() -> {
            synchronized (lock) {
                lock.notifyAll();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    class PrintThread implements Runnable {

        private Object lock;
        private String value;

        public PrintThread(String value, Object lock) {
            this.value = value;
            this.lock = lock;
        }

        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        lock.wait();
                        System.out.println(LocalTime.now() + "\t" + value);
                        lock.notifyAll();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I test the program,it stoppted print characters after a few seconds
[image]

Using `jps` and `jstack` I found all the 3 threads are `WAITING` the object lock
[image]

I tested it for serveral times,and this phenomenon occurs every time.

I do not know why **all the 3 threads are waiting object lock at same time**

Based on my knowledge,each time one of the 3 threads will be awake and have the chance to exeute,then it will awake all the 3 threads randomly by invoking `lock.notifyAll();`. So the program should run continuous theoretically,But now each time I test it,it will stop print characters after a few seconds.

Could someone help analysis why this happen? Thanks in advance!

```
        while (true) {
            try {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    lock.wait();
                    System.out.println(LocalTime.now() + "\t" + value);
                    lock.notifyAll();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: If the final thread runs first, the rest will wait indefinitely. That's why you're supposed to check a logical condition before waiting.

Comment: @shmosel, I have posted an image,it will print some characters and then stopped

Comment: I guess they're cycling until they all happen to enter `wait()` at the same time.

Comment: @shmosel,so can you post an answer for it?

Comment: You should check out Mutex and especially the Semaphore class. Both save you from a ton of sync problems.

Comment: @JayC667 I just want to use  `wait` and `notifyAll`

Comment: @Abra Can you provide a more detail explantion for why it's deadlock,thanks in advance!

Comment: @Abra Thanks for post link for `deadlock`,but I still do not undertand I have invoke `notifyAll`,why it can form a deadlock?

Comment: There's no thread to call `notifyAll()` while they're all stuck at `wait()`. Adding a loop to the final thread should "fix" it.

Comment: @Abra I have read it several month ago,now I just want to know why

Comment: @shmosel In my post code,I add a trigger thread to let it `notifyAll` after a period of time

Comment: But it only runs once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are calling `notifyAll()` immediately after calling `wait()`. You get to a deadlock situation where each thread is waiting. When all the threads are waiting, none of them can be notified, hence your program comes to a standstill.

According to the [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) tutorial, you need to `wait()` for a certain condition to occur. Once the condition occurs, you perform the required action (which, in your code, is printing the current time) then you call `notifyAll()` to inform the waiting threads that you have completed performing the required action and that they can try to perform their required action.

Explanations after the code.

```java
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class ThreadPrint4Test {
    private volatile boolean canPrint;

    public void testPrint() {
        Object lock = new Object();
        new Thread(new PrintThread("A", lock), "thread-A").start();
        new Thread(new PrintThread("B", lock), "thread-B").start();
        new Thread(new PrintThread("C", lock), "thread-C").start();
    }

    class PrintThread implements Runnable {
        private Object lock;
        private String value;

        public PrintThread(String value, Object lock) {
            this.value = value;
            this.lock = lock;
            canPrint = true;
        }

        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                while (!canPrint) {
                    try {
                        synchronized (lock) {
                            System.out.printf("[%s] Waiting...%n", value);
                            lock.wait();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
                synchronized (lock) {
                    canPrint = false;
                    System.out.println(LocalTime.now() + "\t" + value);
                    canPrint = true;
                    lock.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ThreadPrint4Test().testPrint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

- I added a `canPrint` flag. When it is true, then the thread can print the current time. When it is false, the thread must wait.
- When the thread can print the current time, it first sets the flag to false so that no other thread can print.
- After the thread has printed the current time, it sets the flag back to true and calls method `notifyAll()` which causes all waiting threads to stop waiting and re-check the `canPrint` flag.
- The first thread to awake after `canPrint` has been set to true, sets the flag to false which causes all other threads to wait.

Comment: How does that work when there a different `canPrint` per PrintThread instance?

Comment: 1) This is NOT how Threading should be done. In crazy situations, even this 'solution' might fail horribly, for example if the system is under heavy load an creating threads takes longer than a second. 2) The solution you posted does not make much sense. Either a) run the separate call to `notifyAll()` in the 'main thread', i.e. the Thread start runs `testPrint()`, or b) put the sleep mechanism inside that additional Thread you start.

Comment: @JayC667 The additional thread calling notifyAll is not needed -- I think it should be removed from the answer

Comment: @tgdavies If you want the call to `testPrint()` to return immediately, without waiting, you'd need that Thread, and put the sleeping inside it. But all in all a dangerously bad solution, I'd simply use Mutex or Semaphore, they take care of exactly that problem, and all they do is to use `synchronized` and `.wait()` and `notify()`, so I do not see a reason not to use those but rather trip over simple and unnecessary problems.

Comment: @JayC667 I agree, but the OP specified (in comments) that they wanted to use wait/notify only.

Comment: @Abra this solution will never call `wait`.

Comment: @tgdavies Yes. In the comments. And I told him to take a look, which clearly he didn't, because in the implementation of Semaphore his exact problem is addressed and solved, so if he really wanted that, he could even copy that code/logic behind it and adjust it to his code (and then it could even be good code, because it's really simple to do).

Comment: Actually, to clear that up: Abra already has the right approach using `while (!canPrint) {`. And that's (almost all of) the way to go. I'm merely criticizing the standalone call to `lock.notifyAll();` in `testPrint()`. You would not need that if the 'canPrint' logic was fully implemented.

Comment: This is a bizarre misuse of wait/notify (as was the question, to be fair). You're basically using the `canPrint` variable as a convoluted mutex overlapping with actual synchronization. Put the wait condition inside the `synchronized` block [where it belongs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--), and you'll notice the entire block is dead code. All you really need is a simple loop containing the synchronized code: `while (true) synchronized (lock) { print(...); }`